# How to sort translation under Translate tab?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

[image]

I need to sort these translated language names alphabetically. I want to sort these irrespective of these languages weight and hierarchy. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on "admin/config/regional/language"?
There you can sort languages and the order is reflected throughout the system (e.g.: the language switcher block)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for submitting an answer. This does not seem to answer the user's question regarding the user interface for translators. It might be a good idea to revise the answer that you have to be based on this interface rather than user-facing interfaces.

Comment: As i mentioned, I don't want to sort these w.r.t  weight. Because sorting with weight does not work when we have translation for these languages. @mradcliffe is right.

Comment: Sorry I missed the point here. But sorting of languages in "admin/config/regional/language" is reflected on the node translation page. If you prefer, I can delete my post to avoid further confusion.